# coreos terraform/matchbox doesn't fully install

Tags: pxe-boot, coreos, terraform

I am following this tutorial [matchbox-with-terraform](https://coreos.com/blog/matchbox-with-terraform) which has an end goal of running the [simple-install example](https://github.com/coreos/matchbox/tree/master/examples/terraform/simple-install) which stands up a coreos machine and copies an ssh key over after.

I watch it load the coreos container, please see the [screen recording](https://youtu.be/SXQArTZwfm4) I took (The description has the important time marks, most of the time is a static screen).  It seems that it either finishes loading the image to RAM and reboots or something failed and it reboots but I cannot tell which.  I think the problem lies in my dhcp/tftp iPXE server setup.

I did not modify any of the simple-install terraform example configs.  You can find them in the matchbox-with-terraform tutorial.

BTW I am running a proxy DHCP and TFTP server in a docker container described in the coreos tutorial [here](https://coreos.com/matchbox/docs/0.6.0/network-setup.html#coreosdnsmasq) for iPXE booting.

my docker container is:

```
sudo docker run --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net=host quay.io/coreos/dnsmasq \
-d -q \
--dhcp-range=10.90.239.97,proxy,255.255.255.0 \
--enable-tftp --tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot \  
--dhcp-userclass=set:ipxe,iPXE \  
--pxe-service=tag:#ipxe,x86PC,"PXE chainload to iPXE",undionly.kpxe \  
--pxe-service=tag:ipxe,x86PC,"iPXE",http://10.90.239.223:8080/boot.ipxe \ 
--log-queries \
--log-dhcp
```

some info about my tftp setup

```
$ ls /var/lib/tftpboot/
boot  ipxe.efi  pxelinux.cfg  undionly.kpxe 
$ cat /var/www/html/ipxe/default.ipxe
chain http://10.90.239.223:8080/boot.ipxe
```

So I'm at a loss why it reboots the way it does, I think it is an error that it is.

Any comments on how I can further diagnose this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it turned out my terraform.tfvars had the local host IP

```
$ cat terraform.tfvars
matchbox_http_endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
matchbox_rpc_endpoint = "127.0.0.1:8081"
ssh_authorized_key = "<id_rsa.pub>"
```

instead of the actual servers IP

```
$ cat terraform.tfvars
matchbox_http_endpoint = "http://10.90.239.223:8080"
matchbox_rpc_endpoint = "10.90.239.223:8081"
ssh_authorized_key = "<id_rsa.pub>"
```

fixed that and it worked like a charm.  The example I was following used the localhost IP which is confusing.